# How to use beautifulsoup without installation by keeping it in the project folder on Python?

Tags: python-2.7, import, module

I am running a project at a remote cluster but I do not have root access. Also pip or any other python manager is not installed so I try to include all the files of the beautifulsoup to my project and import them naively. Currently I installed the package to my root folder of the project, I run `python setup.py build` and include the lien to my source code

```
sys.path.append("beautifulsoup/bs4") 
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

However it does not work and the program I wrote cannot see the package.

(My code and the beautifulsoup folder at the same level of folder hierarchy)

How could I make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths cannot be used that way to my knowledge. To append a relative path to `sys.path` you can do:

```
import os, sys
bspath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"beautifulsoup")
sys.path.append(bspath)
```

In your program/script you could then import the library like this:

```
import bs4
```

Comment: this is the error :File "/mnt/interns/golge/FILM_CLASSIFICATION/crawle_imdb/beautifulsoup/bs4/__init__.py", line 29
    from .builder import builder_registry

Comment: it's showing error as follows:
TypeError: dirname() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Now Getting this error: ValueError: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: @bernie any help??

Comment: Yes it is there

Comment: import lxml is working fine, Also i tried moving lxml to my project directory

Comment: tks @bernie, this worked for me. put this in my script `import os, sys
bspath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"BeautifulSoup")
sys.path.append(bspath)
import bs4` and this is what my BS dir looked like `$ ls BeautifulSoup
bs4  PKG-INFO  README.txt  setup.py
`. And the python script was in the same dir that the BS dir was in.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @HattrickNZ. I'm sure it can help others coming across this post.